# Remove Pycharm Breakpoint Thing

Tags: pycharm

So... I really don't know how to phrase this question because I don't know what is happening but there's this thunderbolt icon that pycharm keeps jumping to everytime I save a file and it's incredibly annoying. I've inserted a picture of the icon and if anyone knows how to remove this thing please tell me!

[image]

Comment: I found out you can get rid of it by closing and opening the editor. Still would be nice if someone could explain what this symbol is and how to properly get rid of it.

Answer (score 7):

It is a `Python Exception Breakpoint`. I had accidentally started a process running and the breakpoint was created.

It was not possible for me to delete it using the `Run | View Breakpoints` dialog, I presume because it was on a running process.

Answer:

```
Run | Stop 'your_process'
```

Answer (score 4):

Running Pycharm 3.4.1.

The breakpoint with a lightning bolt through it appears at exceptions within the code. You can control this behavior, as well as breakpoints you have set, by selecting:

```
(1) On the main menu, choose Run|View Breakpoints.
(2) Press Ctrl+Shift+F8.
(3) In the toolbar of the Debug tool window, click the two overlapped red circles.
```

The pop-up screen will look something like:

```
[x] Python Exception Breakpoint
    [x] All exceptions
[ ] Django Exception Breakpoint
    [ ] Template render error
[x] JavaScript Exception Breakpoints
    [x] Any exceptions

[x] All exceptions enabled
[x] Suspend
[ ] Log message to console
[ ] Remove once hit
[ ] Uncaught only
```

Select or deselect the check boxes to obtain the behavior you desire.

Answer (score 0):

I was in trouble with such a matter as this too and I have tried other suggestions. Finally I found the best way. I am using pycharm 2021 and wherever I want to have a breakpoint, I write this code:

```
 breakpoint()
```

For example:

```
#some code

breakpoint()

#other codes
```

Then the program stops and in the terminal it is mentioned where the program is stopped.

After that you can trace your code piece by piece.

Good Luck.